# Codeigniter file cache is limited if we have too many cache files

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, codeigniter-2

Codeigniter file-based caching will take the completely rendered output and save it to the disk. So there is no need to talk to the database or process anything and it is tremendously reducing the server load.

But, It is limited if we have more than 10k files(depends upon server configuration) in cache directory.

So i searched in Google and i found this below code and it is great.

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/110644/

But Now it is also limited for me because, based on md5 first chars, the above code, creates 16 directories. Each directory cache upto 10k files. So overall total is 1,60,000 (approx). But i have a requirement to store more than 5,00,000 cache files.

So the Question is simple, 
        How to configure / change codeigniter file-based caching so that it will handle unlimited cache files?

Please suggest any idea on this.

Comment: Can't you just generalize the linked code to create like 4-5 level of directories, maybe by using 2 chars for each instead of one?

Answer (score 0):

why not change the poster's solution of first md5 char to just be a random string of x number of characters, with his substring, or the random_string function - there is nothing magic about his using first md5 char, it is just to give an extra directory level